# how to solve error invalid spec: spec.arguments.parameters[0].name is required in argo workflow

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, argo-workflows, argo

I am working on argo workflow project

I am passing data from argo sensor to argo workflow from a post request

I two steps in my workflow which will be executed one after another

If a send a post request it triggers the workflow

Here is my code

```
 apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
    kind: Sensor
    metadata:
      name: webhook
      namespace: argo-events
    spec:
      template:
        serviceAccountName: operate-workflow-sa
      dependencies:
        - name: test-dep
          eventSourceName: webhook
          eventName: example
      triggers:
        - template:
            name: webhook-workflow-trigger
            k8s:
              group: argoproj.io
              version: v1alpha1
              resource: workflows
              operation: create
              source:
                resource:
                  apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
                  kind: Workflow
                  metadata:
                    generateName: s3-react-upload-
                  spec:
                    entrypoint: ignite-workflow
                    podGC:
                      strategy: OnPodSuccess
                    deleteDelayDuration: 10s
                    templates:
                      - name: ignite-workflow
                        steps:
                          - - name: React-app-build-and-deploy-to-s3
                              template: Reactappbuildanddeploytos3
                              arguments:
                                parameters:
                                  - name: url
                                    value: hello world
                                  - name: bucket_name
                                    value: hello world
                          - - name: curl-a-Post-method
                              template: curlapostmethod
    
                      - name: Reactappbuildanddeploytos3
                        inputs:
                          parameters:
                            - name: url
                            - name: bucket_name
                          artifacts:
                            - name: argo-source
                              path: /src
                              git:
                                repo: "{{inputs.parameters.url}}"
                        container:
                          image: node:16-alpine3.17
                          command: [sh, -c]
                          args: ["npm install && npm run build"]
                          workingDir: /src
                        outputs:
                          artifacts:
                            - name: message
                              path: /src/build
                              archive:
                                none: {}
                              s3:
                                endpoint: s3.amazonaws.com
                                bucket: "{{inputs.parameters.bucket_name}}"
                                region: eu-west-2
                                key: "."
                                accessKeySecret:
                                  name: mysecret
                                  key: accessKey
                                secretKeySecret:
                                  name: mysecret
                                  key: secretKey
    
                      - name: curlapostmethod
                        container:
                          image: docker/whalesay:latest
                          command: [cowsay]
                          args: ["hello world"]
    
              parameters:
                - src:
                    dependencyName: test-dep
                    dataKey: body.url
                  dest: spec.arguments.parameters.0.value
                - src:
                    dependencyName: test-dep
                    dataKey: body.bucket_name
                  dest: spec.arguments.parameters.1.value
```

But I am getting this error

Failed: invalid spec: spec.arguments.parameters[0].name is required